# Base-learners of Gradient Boosting in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I use `GradientBoostingRegressor` from scikit-learn in a regression problem. In the paper [Gradient boosting machines, a tutorial](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnbot.2013.00021/full), at this part:

> 3.2. Specifying the base-learners
>
> A particular GBM can be designed with different base-learner models on
> board.
>
> ...
>
> The commonly used base-learner models can be classified into three distinct categories: linear models, smooth models and decision
> trees.

They specify the base learner for gradient boosting, but in the relevant scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html), I cannot find the parameter that can specify it .

What is the base-learner used in scikit-learn `GradientBoostingRegressor`? If there is a way to specify the base-learner, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking closer at the documentation page you have [linked](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html) to (emphasis mine):

> In each stage a **regression tree** is fit on the negative gradient of the given loss function.

so the base estimator here is a [decision tree regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html).

You cannot change the base regressor here; to do so you'll have to revert to the [`AdaBoostRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.html) model, which is somewhat similar but not identical to the gradient boosting one.

Keep in mind that, while in theory the paper you link is correct, there is a reason why boosting algorithms in practice are used mostly with decision trees as base estimators. Very briefly (not the place for a complete exposition), decision trees exhibit an inherent instability which makes their boosted (and bagging) ensembles particularly useful, something that does not hold for algorithms like, say, linear models or SVMs.